# Depends: libssl0.9.8 (>= 0.9.8m-1) but it is not installable

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, libssl

I'm trying to install nginx (Debian 7, amd64):

```
apt-get install nginx
```

But I get an error:

> nginx : Depends: libssl0.9.8 (>= 0.9.8m-1) but it is not installable

I downloaded the deb and install it:

```
wget http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20110406T213352Z/pool/main/o/openssl098/libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7_i386.deb
```

But this has no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: to tell the world why this is happening: debian 7 comes with libssl1.0.0, and can't downgrade to 0.9.8 (which is the dependency of nginx) while nginx installation...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution:**

To install nginx on Debian 7 you should add it in */etc/apt/sources.list* :

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ wheezy nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ wheezy nginx
```

Comment: I found it necessary to also add the PGP key by following the instructions on http://wiki.nginx.org/Pgp 

(summary: download the pgp key and install it with `apt-key add <key>`)